# find method not returning '0th' matched object react, or react-native or javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Not getting all matched objects, its is returning all objects except '{ ID:0, Name: 'General Group' }', i want all matched objects

```js
 let arrDashboardIconGroups = [
      { ID:0, Name: 'General Group' },
      { ID: 1, Name: 'Patient Administration' },     
      { ID: 2, Name: 'Medical Charts' },
      { ID: 3, Name: 'Medical Procedures' },
      { ID: 13, Name: 'Purchase' },
      { ID: 14, Name: 'Sales' },
      { ID: 5, Name: 'Insurance' },
      { ID: 4, Name: 'Cash' },
      { ID: 6, Name: 'Pharmacy' },
      { ID: 7, Name: 'Inventory' },
      { ID: 8, Name: 'Lab' },
      { ID: 9, Name: 'Imaging' },
      { ID: 10, Name: 'In Patient' },
      { ID: 11, Name: 'System Administration' },
      { ID: 12, Name: 'Accounting' }
  ]  

const getMatchedobjects=()=> {

   let result = [0,1,2,3,4,]
   let matchedArray = arrDashboardIconGroups.filter(val =>result.find(
      (items)=>items == val.ID))

   console.log(matchedArray)
}

getMatchedobjects()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

Find returns a value/object (the first matching), but it seems you want to filter the `arrDashboardIconGroups` array by those that match an `id` specified in the `result` array. When `result[0]` is returned, `0` is the value, which is falsey, and the filter doesn't return the element from the `arrDashboardIconGroups` array.

## Solution

Use `Array.prototype.some` to return the boolean that `filter` needs to include an element in the result array.

```js
let arrDashboardIconGroups = [
  { ID:0, Name: 'General Group' },
  { ID: 1, Name: 'Patient Administration' },     
  { ID: 2, Name: 'Medical Charts' },
  { ID: 3, Name: 'Medical Procedures' },
  { ID: 13, Name: 'Purchase' },
  { ID: 14, Name: 'Sales' },
  { ID: 5, Name: 'Insurance' },
  { ID: 4, Name: 'Cash' },
  { ID: 6, Name: 'Pharmacy' },
  { ID: 7, Name: 'Inventory' },
  { ID: 8, Name: 'Lab' },
  { ID: 9, Name: 'Imaging' },
  { ID: 10, Name: 'In Patient' },
  { ID: 11, Name: 'System Administration' },
  { ID: 12, Name: 'Accounting' }
];

const getMatchedobjects = () => {
  let result = [0,1,2,3,4,];
  let matchedArray = arrDashboardIconGroups.filter(val => result.some((items)=>items == val.ID));

  console.log(matchedArray);
}

getMatchedobjects();
```

Alternatively you could also check that `result` array includes the matching `id`.

```js
let arrDashboardIconGroups = [
  { ID:0, Name: 'General Group' },
  { ID: 1, Name: 'Patient Administration' },     
  { ID: 2, Name: 'Medical Charts' },
  { ID: 3, Name: 'Medical Procedures' },
  { ID: 13, Name: 'Purchase' },
  { ID: 14, Name: 'Sales' },
  { ID: 5, Name: 'Insurance' },
  { ID: 4, Name: 'Cash' },
  { ID: 6, Name: 'Pharmacy' },
  { ID: 7, Name: 'Inventory' },
  { ID: 8, Name: 'Lab' },
  { ID: 9, Name: 'Imaging' },
  { ID: 10, Name: 'In Patient' },
  { ID: 11, Name: 'System Administration' },
  { ID: 12, Name: 'Accounting' }
]; 

const getMatchedobjects=()=> {
  let result = [0,1,2,3,4,];
  let matchedArray = arrDashboardIconGroups.filter(val => result.includes(val.ID)) ;

  console.log(matchedArray);
}

getMatchedobjects();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are returning the value of

```
result.find((items) => items == val.ID)
```

**In the first case, the value returned is `0` which is a `falsy` value. So It won't include in the final filter result.**

You can run the below code and see the returning values.

```js
let arrDashboardIconGroups = [
  { ID: 0, Name: "General Group" },
  { ID: 1, Name: "Patient Administration" },
  { ID: 2, Name: "Medical Charts" },
  { ID: 3, Name: "Medical Procedures" },
  { ID: 13, Name: "Purchase" },
  { ID: 14, Name: "Sales" },
  { ID: 5, Name: "Insurance" },
  { ID: 4, Name: "Cash" },
  { ID: 6, Name: "Pharmacy" },
  { ID: 7, Name: "Inventory" },
  { ID: 8, Name: "Lab" },
  { ID: 9, Name: "Imaging" },
  { ID: 10, Name: "In Patient" },
  { ID: 11, Name: "System Administration" },
  { ID: 12, Name: "Accounting" },
];

const getMatchedobjects = () => {
  let result = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
  let matchedArray = arrDashboardIconGroups.filter((val) => {
    const returnResult = result.find((items) => items == val.ID);
    console.log(returnResult);
    return returnResult;
    // result.includes(val.ID)
  });

  console.log(matchedArray);
};

getMatchedobjects();
```

Alternatively, you can use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
let arrDashboardIconGroups = [
  { ID: 0, Name: "General Group" },
  { ID: 1, Name: "Patient Administration" },
  { ID: 2, Name: "Medical Charts" },
  { ID: 3, Name: "Medical Procedures" },
  { ID: 13, Name: "Purchase" },
  { ID: 14, Name: "Sales" },
  { ID: 5, Name: "Insurance" },
  { ID: 4, Name: "Cash" },
  { ID: 6, Name: "Pharmacy" },
  { ID: 7, Name: "Inventory" },
  { ID: 8, Name: "Lab" },
  { ID: 9, Name: "Imaging" },
  { ID: 10, Name: "In Patient" },
  { ID: 11, Name: "System Administration" },
  { ID: 12, Name: "Accounting" },
];

const getMatchedobjects = () => {
  let result = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
  let matchedArray = arrDashboardIconGroups.filter((val) => result.includes(val.ID));

  console.log(matchedArray);
};

getMatchedobjects();
```

Comment: Finally an explanation why the first element is missing in the result set of OP

Answer (score 0):

`find()` returns value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function. Since `0` is a falsy value, it does not include it in the final array. [See MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

You can `map` the `result` array, and use `arrDashboardIconGroups`'s  `find` function, and return the matching objects.

```js
let arrDashboardIconGroups = [
      { ID: 0, Name: 'General Group' },
      { ID: 1, Name: 'Patient Administration' },     
      { ID: 2, Name: 'Medical Charts' },
      { ID: 3, Name: 'Medical Procedures' },
      { ID: 13, Name: 'Purchase' },
      { ID: 14, Name: 'Sales' },
      { ID: 5, Name: 'Insurance' },
      { ID: 4, Name: 'Cash' },
      { ID: 6, Name: 'Pharmacy' },
      { ID: 7, Name: 'Inventory' },
      { ID: 8, Name: 'Lab' },
      { ID: 9, Name: 'Imaging' },
      { ID: 10, Name: 'In Patient' },
      { ID: 11, Name: 'System Administration' },
      { ID: 12, Name: 'Accounting' }
  ]  

const getMatchedobjects=()=> {

   let result = [0, 1,2,3,4,99]   //99 for trial
   let matchedArray = result.map((res)=>arrDashboardIconGroups.find((val)=>val.ID == res)).filter(Boolean);

   console.log(matchedArray)
}

getMatchedobjects()
```

Comment: _"i want all matched objects"_ - `.map()` returns all elements regardless of a matching element

Comment: @Andreas Sorry, I am not able to get you. The `matchedArray` has all the objects that have their `ID` in `result` array.

Comment: Yes, but then result will have an unnecessary `undefined` if an element from `result` has no corresponding element in `arrDashboardIconGroups`. Add `99` to `result` and check the log.